# Diffrence between Function and Generic Function in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

i want to know the difference between the Function and Generic function in swift.Following 
Function and Generic function is doing same..can anyone tell me the exact use of Generic functions ?

```
func simpleMin<T: Comparable>(x: T, y: T) -> T {  //Generic functions
    if x < y {
        return y
    }
    return x
}


func sampleMin(x:AnyObject,y:AnyObject)->AnyObject{  //Function
    if x.integerValue < y.integerValue {
        return y
    }
    return x
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic functions let you use the type safety of Swift on both the parameters and the result of the function to write safer, cleaner code. For example, your first function requires that both parameters passed in be of the same type, and guarantees a return value of that same type:

```
let minInt: Int = simpleMin(5, 12)
let minDouble: Double = simpleMin(5.0, 12.0)
```

whereas your second function makes no such requirements and no such guarantee:

```
let minOne: AnyObject = sampleMin(5, 12.0)     // minOne is an AnyObject holding an Int
let minTwo: AnyObject = sampleMin(5.0, 12)     // minTwo is an AnyObject holding an Double
let minThree: AnyObject = sampleMin("Five", true)   // what is supposed to happen here, exactly?
```

With these `AnyObject` results I would need to do extra checks to make sure I understand what the function returned, since `AnyObject` is (obviously) much less specific than my original parameters.

Moreover, generic functions allow you to put constraints on the parameters they accept, so you can make sure that the function is called only with arguments that make sense. Your first function  requires that the parameters conform to the `Comparable` protocol, meaning that I can't just call it with two random objects. The compiler will let me call your second function with two instances of `UIView`, for example, and there won't be any problem until the crash when that code is executed.

---

Understanding **protocols** is an important part of using generics. A protocol defines some specific functionality that would be useful across a whole range of classes, and leaves the implementation of that functionality up to the classes themselves. The `Comparable` protocol above is one example; here's the definition:

```
protocol Comparable : Equatable {
    func <=(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
    func >=(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
    func >(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}
```

This is saying that any object that "conforms to" the `Comparable` protocol is going to have definitions for using the `<=`, `>=`, and `>` operators -- that is, you'd be able to write `if a > b` for any two objects that are both `Comparable`.

---

**More reading:**
[The Swift Programming Language: Generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Generics.html)
[Generic Programming - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming)

Generics have long been a feature of C# and Java, among other languages, so you may find more resources to help you understand their benefits and how to use them in their documentation.

Comment: can you please tell me how may functions are there like"equatable","comparable"..etc ?

Comment: Those are both protocols - Swift has several built in, the Cocoa frameworks have a ton more, and you can define your own, as well: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Protocols.html

Answer (score 3):

1. Generic function is more descriptive and type Safe:
   Example : If it is generic function calling the function with wrong type results in compile time error
   i.e

   **simpleMin(100, y: 200)** // Valid as type is same as T
   **simpleMin(someOtherTypedObject, y: 100.0)** // Compile time error due to mismatch in type
2. Generic type can have Type constraints which specify that a type parameter must inherit from a specific class, or conform to a particular protocol or protocol composition. But its not possible to specify type constraints to **AnyObjectType**

i.e the bellow declaration gives compile time error

```
func sampleMin(x:AnyObject<Comparable>,y:AnyObject<Comparable>)->AnyObject{  //Error: Cann't specialize the nonGeneric type **AnyObject**
    if x.integerValue < y.integerValue {
        return y
    }
    return x
}
```

In Second function definition you can't make sure that variables passed are comparable.

Comment: One more built in Protocol "Equatable" is there , You can define any protocols you want.