# What's the point of generics with the Any type?

Tags: swift

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I've just been reading the swift docs, and I can't figure out the point of generics.

If I have the following:

```
func swapTwoInts<T>(inout a: T, inout b: T) {
let tempa = a
a = b
b = tempa
}

var num1 = "uno"
var num2 = "dos"
swap(&num1, &num2)
```

How is

```
func swapTwoInts (inout a: Any, inout b: Any) {
let tempa = a
a = b
b = tempa
}


var num1 = "uno"
var num2 = "dos"
swap(&num1, &num2)
```

any different? Where are some examples where you HAVE to use generics and not the Any type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Generic functions let you use the type safety of Swift on both the parameters and the result of the function to write safer, cleaner code. "

There is the same question (and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378452/diffrence-between-function-and-generic-function-in-swift))

Comment: Oh, so it's a fancy code quality thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are just handy ways to not have to rewrite the same code for a different data type. Say you wanted two swap to strings as well as two ints at different times in your program - either write two functions doing the exact same thing or have one generic function.